# Psycopg3 unable to connect async

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, psycopg3

Unable to connect postgres database using async psycopg3 :

```
import asyncio
import psycopg

async def main():
    async with await psycopg.AsyncConnection.connect('postgresql://xxxxxxxxxxx') as con:
        async with con.cursor() as cur:
            print(await cur.execute('select 1 a').fetchall())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I get error:

```
psycopg.InterfaceError: Psycopg cannot use the 'ProactorEventLoop' to run in async mode. Please use a compatible event loop, for instance by setting 'asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())'
```

On Windows 10, Python 3.9, Psycopg 3.0.8

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message suggested?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working solution

```
import asyncio
import sys

import psycopg


async def main():

    async with await psycopg.AsyncConnection.connect('postgresql://xxxxxxxxxxx') as con:
        async with con.cursor() as cur:
            print(await (await cur.execute('select 1 a')).fetchall())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if sys.platform == "win32":
        asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).